# Making a high-temp, battery-operated, heating/burning device

Tags: heat, battery-operated, heater, ptc

Crazily enough, this is not for recreational smoking use.

I am trying to create a small, battery powered device, that can hit temps around 250 to 350 degrees Celsius (482 to 662 degrees Fahrenheit), in order to ignite/smoke the debris for a prototype outdoor appliance I am working on.

I have no experience with anything outside of basic household electric wiring, so I am definitely considered a beginner.

I’m trying to determine if the idea will work, and if so I will definitely have to refine the prototype.

Currently I have:

- A 12V PTC (Aluminum-coated) heating element
- 8 AA battery pack (series)

The heating element has no Wattage listed and claims it has a max temp of 428F (which would be under my min needed).

Comment: What kind of debris are you planning to ignite? This seems irresponsible and environmentally unfriendly.

Comment: Should be no issue achieving those specs, but the choice of 8AA cells is prob not the best. I’d look at hacking a battery powered hot air gun. The battery drill style battery packs will give you more than enough energy to reach your target.

Comment: @uriyabsc actually just the opposite. Completely safe and environmentally friendly way of reusing certain forms of kitchen waste to deter pests. Like I mentioned, this is to be a crude prototype to help with proof of concept. Thanks for your concern though

Comment: @Kartman glad to hear it shouldn’t be difficult to achieve those specs. I will definitely look into a battery powered hot air gun. I completely agree with you that 8 AA cells are not sustainable long term, but I don’t have any experience outside of basic HS physics class and some electrical wiring, so I really have no idea what I am doing! Thank you for responding!

Comment: @Greyshoes What kind of kitchen waste are you planning to ignite? You can't just ignite anything in your backyard.

Comment: @uriyabsc Surely that depends on where you live. Towns, counties, states and countries all have different local and national laws that govern what, if and where you can burn something.

Comment: @PeterJennings Which is exactly why I'm trying to understand what OP is intending to ignite, possibly breaking the law and endangering themselves and their environment in the process.

Comment: ***NOTE*** Three of the 8 comments are by one user re environmental aspects and not related to the question per se.  I suggest that the point (whether valid or not) has been well enough made and you may wish to open a chat session if you want to comment further on this aspect. || If this theme continues I'll move the discussion to chat **BUT** I'd rather users sorted such things out temselves.

Answer (score 0):

The wattage of the heater can be determined by powering it from 12 V and measuring the current.
Power = Volts x Amps.

AA batteries are a terrible energy source for heating at more than trivially low and/or very short time periods. 8 x AA Alkaline cells will give you maybe 10 to 20 Wh at not more than 1A and ideally less.
Much more current and they will sag quickly.

For experimenting using almost any small lead acid 12V battery would be far better - make it smaller once you know what you want. 12V 7Ah alarm  & motorcycle batteries are lowish cost. 3 Ah and even 1.2 Ah are available.

4 x LiIon 18650 cells would work well.

It is likely that the PTC heater uses more power than you can afford and perhaps less heat.

A posibly better solution is to use Nichrome wire - either new or from an old appliance such as a toaster or room heater. This can be used at whatever length of wire suits and multiple strands can be used if wanted.